# Immunity from Metal

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm making a villain for my party to go up against, who is a metal manipulator.  Not sure yet if I'm going to have his power be magnetism or just metal shaping.

Anyway, his super outfit is, of course, made of metal.

The problem comes in when one of the heroes has the ability to manipulate metal as well, and isn't the type to worry about the morality of making bad guys armour grow spikes into them.  And when another of my intrepid 'heroes' uses guns and likes filling people with lead.

So the obvious answer to the second hero, to me at least, is to make him immune to damage from things made of metal.  His powers just kind of make anything metal stop just before it can harm him, whether it be bullets, brass knuckles, baseball bats, whatever.  But that still leaves his suit as manipulable by the first hero.  How do I stop that, how do I make it so every round my villain isn't distracted by constantly having to undo his suit fusing together?

Is it an Immunity to Magnetic Effects?  Immunity to Damage from Metal?  Immunity to Metal Effects?  A Reaction power of some type?  Do I just make it an unstated Power Stunt?  And how do I stat the costs of such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The character could have an Immunity power.

The [Immunity](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/immunity-defense/) effect can protect a character against certain damage or power descriptors, which may be what you have in mind.

> You assign ranks of Immunity to various effects to gain immunity to them (with more extensive effects requiring more ranks).

This power is constant and requires no action or reaction to use. Depending on what immunities this NPC should have, and which powers you want to protect them against, their Immunity would be 5 or 10 ranks. This costs 1 power point per rank.

> 5 ranks: alteration effects, sensory Affliction effects, emotion effects, entrapment (grabbing, snares, or bonds), fatigue effects, interaction skills, or a particular Damage effect, descriptor (such as bullets, cold, electricity, falling, fire, magic, radiation, sonic, etc.)
>
> 10 ranks: a common power descriptor (such as all effects with cold, electricity, fire, radiation, or weather descriptors, for example), life support (includes immunity to disease, poison, all environmental conditions, suffocation, and starvation and thirst).

5 ranks could give them immunity to Damage with one descriptor. You could make them immune to damage (metal), or damage (magnetism). However, they would still be susceptible to Affliction or Move Object effects with those descriptors.

Alternatively, 10 ranks could give them immunity to all effects with a given descriptor. So Immunity 10 (metal effects) or Immunity 10 (magnetism effects) could be a strong defensive option against a metal-controller opponent.

Comment: That's what the Hero's Handbook says, yes, but Power Profiles lists Immunity to Magnetism Effects at 5 points, and considering mooks and such use guns, wouldn't Immunity to Metal Effects be more under the 'very common' damage descriptor, making it a 20 point cost?  This is why I'm having so much trouble deciding how to stat 'is immune to metal hitting him and people manipulating any metal in or on his person'.

Comment: The 5 point cost in the Power Profile is odd. Maybe a typo. As for whether metal is common enough that Immunity would cost 20 pp, that's for the GM to decide.

Comment: Which is me as he's a villain, and really shouldn't be too much of a problem as he has unlimited Power Points as such.  But then I think of my metal manipulating player asking for the same sort of power once his PP is saved up enough and I really have to think on cost.

Ah well, you have a point, it's down to me in the end.  Probably going with 10 points, as there's still a lot of damage dealers out there that aren't metal, and 'metal' is more in line with the descriptors in the 10 point section like radiation, weather, and fire, than the 20 point section that has bludgeoning and energy.

Comment: As a side note, the Power Profiles are all over the place on cost, possibly the result of multiple contributors. But yes, Immunities are highly subjective. NPCs get to "cheat" by picking very narrow ones because the GM knows what they're facing. Similarly, be wary of narrow Immunities as AEs or Variable effects by the PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here. First, yes, you can build an Immunity, whether it's to "metal" effects in general, to the descriptor of the metal-bending guy's power, or even the very narrow 1 PP setup of "one person/family's powers" for him having built or bought a specific counter-measure.

Second, remember that worn/wielded items have to be targeted and get to resist, and people don't just gain powers from descriptors. Your metal-bending guy can buy Damage or Affliction to model those effects, but he doesn't get it just by being able to use Transform or Move Object on a piece of stationary metal.